# Show the wind direction in degree in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, weather, weather-api

How to show the wind direction in a degree of 90° in javascript (including the use of the small circle degree symbol after the number)?

I could only show in the textual description - code below.

thank you.

```js
function text(d) {
  let directions = ['Northerly', 'North Easterly', 'Easterly', 'South Easterly', 'Southerly', 'South Westerly', 'Westerly', 'North Westerly'];

  d += 22.5;

  if (d < 0)
    d = 360 - Math.abs(d) % 360;
  else
    d = d % 360;

  let w = parseInt(d / 45);
  return `${directions[w]}`;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info such as  value for ```d``` you are passing here ```text(d) { ... }``` and HTML code as well..

Comment: the value of d is degrees. link - https://jsfiddle.net/yqoxcLfb/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy. Just check utf16 char table and use String.fromChatCode(). Here:

```js
function text(d) {
        let directions = ['Northerly', 'North Easterly', 'Easterly', 'South Easterly', 'Southerly', 'South Westerly', 'Westerly', 'North Westerly'];

        d += 22.5;

        if (d < 0)
            d = 360 - Math.abs(d) % 360;
        else
            d = d % 360;

        let w = parseInt(d / 45);
        return `${directions[w]}`;
    }

    deg = 67;

    console.log(deg + String.fromCharCode(0xfeff00b0) + ' = ' + text(deg));
```

This is one of the many places you can find the UTF16 table:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm
I also corrected an error on your code. Please notice that "degree" variable doesn't exist. Should be "d"

here's a more advanced version of your function for you to study a bit:

```js
dirToStr = (d) => {
  const directions = ['Northerly', 'North Easterly', 'Easterly', 'South Easterly', 'Southerly', 'South Westerly', 'Westerly', 'North Westerly'];
  d = d < 0 ? 
      d = 360 - Math.abs(d) % 360 
    : d % 360;
  return `${directions[d / 45 | 0]}`;
}

const degreeChar = String.fromCharCode(0xfeff00b0);
deg = 67;

console.log(`${deg}${degreeChar} = ${dirToStr(deg)}`);
```

Comment: thank you. I am using a weather API. can I get the wind deg value in the IPA response? link - https://openweathermap.org/forecast5

Comment: Well, you didn't ask that in your initial question. It's better that you make another question asking that, because that's a much more long answer. Basically you have to sign in to the page, get an API key, then make an ajax call to the api to get that info. So you have to educate yourself about ajax calls and asynchronous code and maybe promises. Be aware that it would be better, if you already provide them the API key in the question.

Comment: so I'm using this function to display the wind direction as a 90 degree for each city that is stored in a dropdown menu from differents HTML data files based on the weather IPA. Unfortunately, my code has a lot of files to show therefore I can't make it work here. here is a peace of my code --  https://jsfiddle.net/lmanhaes/gtaso1z6/5/

Comment: SO has as a code editor that is exactly like JSFiddle. Please notice the small "edit the above snippet" below the snippet window. You can transfer your code exactly as it is in JSFiddle to a SO question. Just please don't do that in this one, because it's not what you originally asked. 
If my answer was helpful please don't forget to accept/upvote. Thanks.